# How to make ReportViewer display multiple pages (e.g. one page per DataRow)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, pagination, reportviewer

I'm new to MS reporting. What I'm trying to achieve is to make a simple report which would be filled from a `DataTable` (made programmatically). The idea is to assing data for each page to values from `DataRow`. I.e. report page `1` would get its `TextBox` values from `DataTable.Rows[0]`, report page `2` would display values from `DataTable.Rows[1]` etc. Number of pages = number of `DataRows`.

I've coded a WinForms app that gets a `DataTable` from SQL and filters it based on parameters supplied by user and then displays a Report.

Then I created an empty dummy `DataSet` called `ComplianceFormDataSet` which contains all the field names I will need further. Then I made an `.rdlc`, added a `TextBox` to it with this expression:

```
=Fields!CustomerCode.Value
```

Here's the logic behind passing the data to ReportViewer:

```
DataTable MainDataTable = new DataTable();
MainDataTable.Columns.Add("CustomerCode", typeof(string));
MainDataTable.Rows.Add("Blah1");
MainDataTable.Rows.Add("Blah2");
ReportDataSource MainDataSource = new ReportDataSource("ComplianceFormDataSet", MainDataTable);
MainReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
MainReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(MainDataSource);
MainReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

When I build this a get a report with one page saying `"Blah1"`. How do I make it render two pages: one with `"Blah1"` and the second with `"Blah2"`? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out:

1. Add a List element to the report and stretch it to fill report body.
2. Link the Tablix of this List element to my DataSet.
3. Add a TextBox element inside List element.
4. Select the expression for TextBox element: =Fields!CustomerCode.Value
5. Right-click outside report body and select View -> Grouping.
6. Add a Row Group.
7. In Row Group properties General -> add grouping on CustomerCode field.
8. In Row Group properties Page Breaks -> select Page break options -> Between each instance of a group.
9. If report always generates an extra page with empty fields - open the .rdlc file in XML viewer, find page break tag and remove it.

Pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: which visual studio is this, as this does not follow for vs2008